# problem with automapper I can't access the properties c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have an error by what I want to access the properties of ViewModel

my problem is here

this is my model

[image]

this is my ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModelDemande
{
    public SeDemande seDemandes { get; set; }

    public SeTypeProduit SeTypeProduit { get; set; }
    public  List<SeCritereTest> SeCritereTest { get; set; }
    public SePartenir sePartenirs { get; set; }
    public SeTraitementDemande seTraitementDemandes { get; set; }
    public SeInformationClient SeInformationClient { get; set; }
    public SeClient SeInclient { get; set; }
    public SeAssistantClient assitantclient { get; set; }

    public  SePrestation prestation { get; set; }

    public SeDemandeTypeProduit demandeTypeProduit { get; set; }

    public bool dollar_sgd { get { return seDemandes.DemDollarSgd == true; } set { seDemandes.DemDollarSgd = value; } }
}
```

my problem is here

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SeDemande,ViewModelDemande.SeDemande>(); // Mappage de l'objet Developer à l'objet DeveloperDTO
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please replace the screenshots with code blocks?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy the code as [properly formatted markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [images of code are bad](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and garner downvotes on Stack Overflow

Comment: A list of files or a couple of images aren't models. Post the actual code and the actual compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing a mapping between types:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<SeDemande, ViewModelDemeande>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.seDemande, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your i tried and it works i have a question does this map back and forth?

Comment: In order for it to work back and forth at the end you add .ReverseMap();
If this answer works for you please accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the property should be:

```cs
ViewModelDemande.seDemande
```

Notice the lowercase "s".